# Elegant LINQ solution for finding Max/Min/Avg/etc. euclidean disdance between points

Tags: c#, linq, euclidean-distance

Assume I have list of points and I want to find Max/Min/Avg/etc. euclidean disdance between them. Is there elegant LINQ solution?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Point> points = new List<Point>() { new Point(1, 1), new Point(2, 2), new Point(40, 50), new Point(100, 25) };

    int minEucDistance = ??
}

/// <summary>
/// Return the distance between 2 points
/// </summary>
public static double Euclidean(Point p1, Point p2)
{
    return Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(p1.X - p2.X, 2) + Math.Pow(p1.Y - p2.Y, 2));
}
```

Comment: There is efficient and there is elegant...which do you want?

Comment: @Aron why can't there be both?

Comment: @DavidG Because it involves a hash, which isn't elegant, and a bunch of edge cases you need to efficiently solve for...

Comment: @Maciej Los  elegant means short and clear code that is easy to undestand

Comment: Cross join a la @Andrei is the best then. But it is order O(n^2).

Comment: @BransDs, elegant is easy to understand, true, but it's not equal to "short and clear code that is easy to understnd".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to generate a Cartesian product of all points, effectively producing all possible pairs of points, and then compute euclidean distances between them. Then you will have just a list of distance numbers, so the rest is trivial:

```
var pointWithIndex = points.Select((x, i) => new { Point = x, Index = i});
var pointPairs =
        from p1 in pointWithIndex
        from p2 in pointWithIndex
        where p1.Index > p2.Index
        select { p1 = p1.Point, p2 = p2.Point };

var distances = pointPairs.Select(x => Euclidean(x.p1, x.p2)).ToList();

double minEucDistance = distances.Min();
```

Of course this assumes you do not have a lot of points, cause this is O(n^2).

Comment: Great. And what if I want just calculate distances between points  in it order without permutations. That is distances {p1->p2}, {p2->p3},  {p3->p4}.. realy I meant it.

Comment: @BransDs, well that should nearly obvious, right? Instead of doing a full cartesian product you can just do a single iteration over the list. You can use a plain for, or a Zip for this.

Comment: Not compiling in VS 2013 ..     select { p1 = p1.Point, p2 = p2.Point } -error here

Comment: @BransDs missed _new_ keyword `select new { p1 = p1.Point, p2 = p2.Point } `